# Querying for a range of dates, when date is the only key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to use DynamoDB to store historical stock closing values.
My store will have a few stocks, and grow to include more as requirements change.
I figured I'll have a single table where the only key is `"DATE"` formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

This means that each item in the table will have a `date` key and several attributes of the form `{ TICKER = CLOSING_VALUE }`

Queries for a given date will also filter by a subset of desired stock tickers, e.g. `["INTC", "AAPL"]`.

I am a bit confused since this single key should work both as partition and sort keys.

How should I query to retrieve a subset of stock tickers for a given date range ?

---

*Update*:

I'm creating the table with...

```
{
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    {
      AttributeName: Date,
      AttributeType: S
    }
  ],
  TableName: "Historic",
  KeySchema: [
    {
      AttributeName: Date,
      KeyType: HASH
    }
  ]
}
```

And the query:

```
    {
        table_name: "Historic",
        projection_expression: "USD,CAD",
        filter_expression: "#k between :val1 and :val2",
        expression_attribute_names: { "#k" => "Date" },
        expression_attribute_values: {
            ":val1" => "2019-12-01",
            ":val2" => "2020-01-10"
        }
    }
```

And I get an error: 
`Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::ValidationException: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request.`

Comment: You should use `FilterExpression`

Comment: thanks @Alex - I am using FilterExpression (or at least trying to). I am new to dynamoDB so I'm not proficient in the syntax. Also I'd like to know if using the same key (date) for both partition and sorting is correct.

Comment: Yes, You can use just partition key, try to do, if faced with problems update you question with attached code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot sort by - or **efficiently** retrieve a range of - the partition key, you can only sort by the sort key. To understand why, you need to understand how DynamoDB stores its data.

The "partition key" is also called in the [CreateTable operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTable.html#DDB-CreateTable-request-KeySchema) a "hash key" - and indeed it works like a key in a hash table: DynamoDB runs a hash function on this key, and using the resulting number, decides which node(s) of its large cluster should hold this partition. This approach allows distributing the table across the cluster, but it makes it **impossible** to efficiently retrieve the different partitions ordered by their key. The "Scan" operation will return the partitions in seemingly-random order (they are likely to be sorted by the hash function of their key), and it's impossible to efficiently scan just a range of partition keys. It's possible to do this inefficiently - by scanning the entire table and *filtering* just the partitions you want. If I understand correctly, this is what you were trying to do. But this only makes sense for tiny databases - would that be your case?

As you noticed, the other component of the key is the "sort key". Inside a partition, in one node, the different items in of that partition are kept sequentially sorted by the "sort key" order. This allows DynamoDB to efficiently retrieve them sorted in this order, or efficiently retrieve only a range of these sort keys - the `Query` request can do both these things.

So to achieve what you want, you need the date to be the **sort key**, not the partition key. How to do the rest of the data modeling depends on what your typical queries look like:

If you have a large number of stocks, but a typical query only asks for a handful of stocks, the most reasonable approach is to use the stock name as the partition key, and as I said, the data as the sort key. This will allow you to efficiently `Query` a date range for one particular stock - and if you need 3 different stocks, you'll need to do 3 `Query`s (you can and should do them in parallel!) but each of these queries will be efficient and you'll only be paying for the actual data you retrieve, without any post-filtering.

If there is a huge number of different dates (e.g, you keep data at 1 second resolution), your partitions can grow huge, and for various reasons this is not recommended. In such a case, you can split each partition into multiple partition by some coarse time window. For example, instead of having one huge partition for stock "GOOG", have one partition "GOOG Nov 2019", one "GOOG Dec 2019", etc. When you query a small date range, you'll know which specific partition you need to read from. But when the query spans more than one month, you'll need to query multiple of these partitions. Note that very large queries will read (and return) huge amounts of data, so will be very expensive, so you're only likely to want to do this in large analytic jobs.

Comment: Thanks Nadav, worked like a charm. Refactoring the stock symbol to be the partition showed me that I need to think differently when it comes to dynamoDB. Still figuring out how to do parallel queries from Ruby.